# Spark cores and memory management

Tags: apache-spark

We're running spark 1.4.0 on ec2, with 6 machines, 4 cores each. We're trying to run an application on a number of total-executor-cores. but we want it to run on the minimal number of machines as possible (e.g. total-executor-cores=4, we'll want single machine. total-executor-cores=12, we'll want 3 machines)

I'm running spark shell, in the following command:

`/root/spark/bin/spark-shell --total-executor-cores X --executor-cores 4`

or

`/root/spark/bin/spark-shell --total-executor-cores X`

and checked the cores on the spark UI, and found the following:

```
Req total-executor-cores    Actual cores with executor-cores param  Actual cores without executor-cores=4 param
24  24  24
22  22  16
20  20  8
16  16  0
12  12  0
8   8   0
4   4   0
```

our questions:

1. Why we don't always get the number of cores we asked for when passing the "executor-cores 4" parameter? It seems that the number of cores we actually get is something like "max(24-(24-REQ_TOTAL_CORES)*4, 0)"
2. How can we get our original request? get the cores in minimal number of machines? When playing with the `executor-cores`, we have the problem described in (1), but the cores are on minimal number of cores
3. Playing with the parameter `spark.deploy.spreadOut` didn't seem to help with our request

Thanks,

nizan

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong, by default spark is configured as 1 executor by cluster node, so I'm not an expert but I think what you want to is something like this for 1 machine and 4 cores (assuming you have default configuration)

```
/root/spark/bin/spark-shell --executor-cores 4 --num-executors 1
```

And this for 3 machine and 12 cores

```
/root/spark/bin/spark-shell --total-executor-cores 12 --num-executors 3
```

As I said before I'm not an expert but I think **--executor-cores 4** means every executor (by default every cluster node) will use 4 cores while **--total-executor-cores 12** means that will be used 12 cores across all executors. Also I think by default spark would try to use all possible cores according the number of executors available so maybe the first sentence to launch spark would be enough with

```
/root/spark/bin/spark-shell --num-executors 1
```

Because every executor has 4 cores (again, assuming you have default configuration).

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: I still didn't get that to work 
The parameter --num-executors is only valid when using YARN (and mesos I think). However, I'm using a standalone cluster

By default, spark tries to use as many machines as it can (you asked for 10 total-executor-cores, so if it's possible, spark will allocate it in 10 different machines)

I would like, if possible, to use few machines as possible (for the 10 cores requested, give me 3 machines)

Comment: Sorry @NizanGrauer, you are right --num-executors is for YARN. if I find out something else I'll let you know